# Programmatic focussing of parent Window from a Popup

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, focus

I am currently having an issue with a WPF Popup where an action on said popup wants to return the Focus to the Main window of the application.

Usually, when you click somewhere on the window the popup closes, which is the desired behaviour. However, **I found no programmatic way to bring the focus back to the window from an action inside the popup in much the same way**.

The following code outlines the problem:

*Xaml:*

```
<Window x:Class="PopupFocusEtc.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" x:Name="_wdw">
    <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition /><ColumnDefinition />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox x:Name="_txt" Text="Test" 
                 Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
        <Button Grid.Row="1" x:Name="_btnOpen" 
                Click="OpenPopup" 
                Content="Open Popup" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
        <Popup x:Name="_popup" 
               Placement="Bottom" 
               HorizontalOffset="10"
               PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=_btnOpen}"
               StaysOpen="False">
          <Button Click="SwitchFocus" 
                  MinHeight="100" MinWidth="100" 
                  Margin="5"
                  Content="Focus" />
        </Popup>
        <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" 
                   Fill="DarkOliveGreen">
          <Rectangle.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
              <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                  <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
                </Trigger>
              </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
          </Rectangle.Style>
        </Rectangle>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

*code-behind:*

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace PopupFocusEtc
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void OpenPopup(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _popup.IsOpen = true;
        }

        private void SwitchFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _txt.Focus();
            Keyboard.Focus(_txt);
            _txt.SelectAll();
            _wdw.Activate();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of the running app]
[image: Popup being open]

When I click the button in the popup what happens is that the textbox gets correctly focussed, I can even enter text, but the Popup **stays open**. Also, note the MouseOver effect on the rectangle that switches the cursor to a hand. Even though the window has focus, **the effect is not working**.

Only when I **click into the window** will the popup disappear, the effect works again, etc.

My question is: **Given this situation, How do I get the main window activated again in such a way as if I would have clicked it?**

**UPDATE**

I know that in the given example I can simply *close the popup in the code-behind*. This is a simplified example - In another app, the action started from within the Popup UI *doesn't know that it lives on a Popup*, and whatever happens on the main window *doesn't know about the popup either*.

Hence, before introducing more coupling in the UI, I would like to know if the mechanism that runs off when you click into the window can somehow be triggered programmatically...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear on whether or not the example you provide above mimics the desired approach, but if you just add the line:

```
 _popup.IsOpen = false;
```

in the `SwitchFocus` method (I would put it before the `_wdw.Activate()`, but it also works after), then the popup closes when you click the button, and the `TextBox` receives focus.

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, I should have added that to the question and I will. In the actual application where this happens the part that will focus something on the main window really doesn't know anything about the action coming from the popup - so, before I resort to coupling the popup instance to the action that triggers the focusing I am searching how to activate the window "properly" as clicking into it does.

Comment: So are you saying that you'd prefer the popup has no knowledge of the textbox?  Or of the parent window?

Comment: The point is that there is a mechanism that closes the popup and activates the window, which you can see in action when you simply click on the window. If I can leverage that, I don't need to know anything about a popup.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think the mechanism you're referring to is just logic in the Popup to close itself when it loses focus.  There is a popup setting which lets you turn this off (so it stays open even when focus is lost).  I don't think it has anything to do with the window/component that receives focus.  If you haven't already, I'd suggest looking at the WPF Focus Overview to see if one of the focus events can do what you're looking for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768.aspx